# How to say a "strong flavor"

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I know that currently people in Chinese would say "很重的味道“。 But I'm wondering if there are any other ways of saying it. 
Could I say "很大的味道 “ or ”很浓的味道“ if I'm referring to something like a hot sauce?

Comment: At my first glance, `很重/很大/很浓的味道` implies *smelly* if without any context. For flavor, "很重的 **口味**" is more specific.

Answer (score 1):

很大/很重/很浓/很冲 these words are common. 很大 is used for SMELL. 很重 more for TASTE and has a negative feel(A very popular word now in China is 重口, which is somehow similar to HARDCORE).很浓 is used to describe liquid or smell.(It is also used to describe a feeling. 爱意很浓 means love is very strong. 睡意很浓 means very sleepy )As for 很冲 it means the smell/taste is spicy like pepper or mustard(脾气很冲 means hot-tempered),.

Comment: 重口 = 重口味, right?

Comment: yes. it's in short.@user3306356